# Glassfish - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/primefaces/model/UploadedFile

Tags: java, maven, primefaces, glassfish-4

I have a maven based project. This is how the project looks like in eclipse:

[image]

So I have separate front and back end that are packed into one `EAR`. The application were deployed on `Weblogic 12c server` but now I have to move it to `Glassfish`. I can deploy to `Glassfish` and my application is running. But, i got an error message when I invoke a method which use `Primefaces UploadFile` class. This is the error message:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/primefaces/model/UploadedFile
javax.ejb.EJBException: java.rmi.ServerError: Error occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/primefaces/model/UploadedFile
```

This two dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.3</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
    <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
    <version>6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Are in both `POM.xml` (front and back end) And the maven dependency is in my classpath as you can see in this picture:

[image]

My question is, where should I put the Primefaces jar, to make visible for `Glassfish` in runtime?

Comment: I've found Maven's plugins useful for issues like this in the past, they give you a whole lot of control over how you can package dependencies with the war, jar, or ear. Specifically the Maven Assembly plugin or Maven Ear plugin - with these you can include the project dependencies in the build. Another way may be to manually add the library to the /lib directory of Glassfish, you may have previously done that on Weblogic?

Comment: OHH!!! I added the primefaces to this folder: /Oracle/glassfish4/glassfish/lib and it's working now! Thank you! please write and answer and i will accept. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll either need to add the dependencies to the ***/lib*** folder of Glassfish as this is where the container will check for them, **or** bundle them up with the deployable artifact - in your case the .ear file. As you are using maven there are a couple of plugins available that may help you e.g. the Maven Assembly or Maven Ear plugins.

-Answer based on my comment above.